# update preview field after submitting the value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model for storing document numbering where the fields to fill are document, prefix, suffix, length and start. This I could do but after filling those data I need to show preview field in the table and preview field is based on the prefix, suffix and length.

What I mean to say is if I fill the prefix as 1, suffix as -2345 and length as 4 then the preview should be for that document as

```
1xxxx-2345
```

if prefix as he-, suffix as -7459 and length as 5 then the preview should be

```
he-xxxxx-7459
```

This can be done with the following logic

```
preview = str(prefix)+(('x')*length)+str(sufix)
```

But how can I implement this in django. Do I have to use signals or override save method? Can anyone give me an idea, please?

Here is my model

```
class DocumentNumbering(models.Model):
    office = models.OneToOneField(OfficeSetup, blank=True, null=True)
    document = models.OneToOneField(Document blank=False, null=False)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sufix = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False, validators=[
                                         MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)])

    // not sure where to implement the logic for preview
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Also I just thought i'd add that, if you decide to use the approach of overriding the `save()` method then be careful of using functions such as `bulk_create()` as it doesn't call `save()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to store this in the database? If it is just for display purposes you could use a derived property:

```
@property
def preview(self):
    return str(self.prefix)+(('x')*self.length)+str(self.sufix)
```

Comment: I am not sure which approach is the best. The approach I know is one you posted as a solution, another save and another signal. Among this three which one will be the better and why? Can you please enlighten me? It will help me to utilize the right approach for the required situation.

Comment: I get confuse on save and signal. property part I understand but save vs signal I am still in confusion.

Comment: What are your requirements for the field? If it is just for displaying in a table then I would definitely recommend using the `@property` method. However if you need to perform operations on the field, such as querying it, then you'd want the database to handle that.

Comment: I need to save in the database so I can search from that preview value .

Comment: In that case I'd recommend overriding the `save()` method to update the preview field (which it looks like you'll have to create a migration for, to update your database table). That will ensure that your database field for preview always matches up to the fields for prefix, suffix, and length (so long as you don't use something like `bulk_create()`. Signals would be best if some other model needed to keep track of what was happening in this model.